# Switch statement in C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int score;
    char grade;
    cout << "Enter your score: " << endl;
    cin >> score;
    if (score >= 90)
        grade = 'a';
    if (score >= 80)
        grade = 'b';
    if (score >= 70)
        grade = 'c';
    if (score >= 60)
        grade = 'd';
    else
        grade = 'f';

    cout << grade << endl;

    switch (grade) {
        case 'a':
            cout << "Good job" << endl;
            break;
        case 'c':
            cout << "Fair job" << endl;
            break;
        case 'f':
            cout << "Failure" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "invalid" << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it giving my default switch case when I enter `95` when I should be getting case 'a'?

Comment: Why are you converting the number to a letter and then the letter to a longer worded description? Skip the `switch` and print both in your first `if` (after you fix it of course). Over-complication is our worst curse, fight against it!

Comment: because `case 'd':` is missing did you notice which grade was being output?

Comment: did you checked the output of the grade before the switch start is it returns **a**

Comment: @Blindy probably because this is a homework assignment illustrating differences between nested if-else-if and switch cases.

Answer (score 8):

You're missing a bunch of `else`s, or doing the comparisons in the wrong order.

95 is greater than 90, but it's also greater than 80, 70 and 60. So you'll get a 'd'.

(And you're not handling 'd' in your switch.)

Answer (score 6):

I believe you want

```
if (score >= 90)
    grade = 'a';
else if (score >= 80)
    grade = 'b';
else if (score >= 70)
    grade = 'c';
else if (score >= 60)
    grade = 'd';
else 
    grade = 'f';
```

What you have does not mutually exclude any but the last two cases, 60 and above and lower. Your code doesn't short circuit; it checks all of 1 through 5.

```
if (score >= 90) // 1.
    grade = 'a';

if (score >= 80) // 2.
    grade = 'b';

if (score >= 70) // 4.
    grade = 'c';

if (score >= 60) // 5.
    grade = 'd';
else 
    grade = 'f';
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use 'else if'. It is falling down to the last if "score >= 60" which is true, and grade then equals "d", which produces the default case in your switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified it such that your 95 satisfies *all* the cases: 95 is bigger than 90, but also bigger than 80, than 70, etc.

In this case, the last one wins.

You can solve it by either using `else`s, or by wrapping it in a function and returning as soon as you know the grade you need:

```
char grade(int score) {
   if (score >= 90) return 'a';
   if (score >= 80) return 'b';
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *if* branches are ordered wrong (or you need to provide *else* branches like so:)).

See it live here: http://ideone.com/2uSZT

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int score;
    char grade;
    cout << "Enter your score:" << endl;
    cin >> score;
    if (score >= 90)
        grade = 'a';
    else if (score >= 80)
        grade = 'b';
    else if (score >= 70)
        grade = 'c';
    else if (score >= 60)
        grade = 'd';
    else
        grade = 'f';

    cout << grade << endl;
    switch (grade)
    {
    case 'a':
        cout << "Good job" << endl;
        break;
    case 'c':
        cout << "Fair job" << endl;
        break;
    case 'f':
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "invalid" << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @mat: you must have flashed on my initial too-quick response? I thought I ninja'd it quick enough :)

Comment: yep, saw your answer pop up while I was writing mine. Got confused a bit by it too :)

Comment: @Mat: see, I know that it is good for something that I make it a point to disregard these popups. The only time it bites me is when I'm finally ready to press 'Submit' and it turns out that the question got deleted

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your *if* statements up top. You should be using *else if*s instead of individual *if*s. Your *if* for 90 is following through, and then so are all the others. Your letter "a" is essentially being overwritten because 95 is >= to all of the other conditions. Using an *else if* will break the rest of the checks when a true one is found.

```
if (score >= 90)
    grade = 'a';
else if (score >= 80)
    grade = 'b';
else if (score >= 70)
    grade = 'c';
else if (score >= 60)
    grade = 'd';
else
    grade = 'f';
```

Answer (score 1):

Because all `score` comparisons are not combined with `if/else if` conditions. They are independent `if` statements. Thus `grade` gets overwritten for `95`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve your *if* conditions.

You are checking `score >= no`. The input `95` executes all the *if* statements and the last executed statement was the `d`. Now in your *switch* statement, `case d` is not present so it executes the `default` one.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten some answers already, but I think I'll suggest a slightly different possibility that gets rid of most of the control flow and substitutes a bit of math:

```
char grades[] = "00000012344";

char *messages[] = {
    "Excellent Job",
    "Good job",
    "Average job",
    "Mediocre Job",
    "Failure"
};

if (score < 0 || score > 100)
    std::cout << "Invalid score";
else {
    int grade = grades[score/10];
    std::cout << messages[grade];
}
```

So, we use `score/10` to turn scores of 0-100 to 0-10. We then look up the appropriate grade for a score, with f=0, d=1, c=2, b=3 and a=4. We use that to select and print out the appropriate message. I've added messages (that may or may not be quite what you want) for the letters you skipped.