# Create a function determine_grade

Tags: function

how can I create a function that determines_grade which accepts the grade between 0-100 and returns the letter grade based on the following scale?
. 90-100 A
. 80-89 B
. 70-79 C
. 60-69 D
. below 60 F

and call my function with each of the following argument

function call     score
1                  90
2                  85
3                  73
4                  62
5                  58

Comment: Does this answer your question? [switch statement c++ help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588364/switch-statement-c-help)

Comment: 13 hours, only 13 views. Please refine the tag.

Comment: Does my answer satisfy your question?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use the `if/elif/else` logic in your function, and since this logic evaluates from the "top-down", after checking if the input is valid, only a single criteria has to be checked at each step. For example:

```
def determine_grade(score):
    if score < 0 or score > 100:
        return "Score not between 0-100"
    elif score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"
```